# Google Cloud ASP.NET Core application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy my app on netcoreapp3.0 to Google Cloud Platform using Google Cloud CLI but there is error:

`No valid .NET Core runtime version found for the app or it is not a supported app.`

As long as I have many depedencies in my app I cannot use another version of .NET Core. Can I get it going somehow?

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: You really should consider building a Docker image and then deploy. That avoids all missing SDK versions and dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

AppEngine Flex and net core only support versions 2.1 and 2.2

As Lex Li said, You really should consider building a customized Docker image.